# How do I change my default session?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, lightdm, gdm3

How do I change the default session I get when I log in? I'm on Debian jessie. I tried changing settings on gdm3, tried installing lightdm and following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456766/how-to-set-default-session-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts) but it's just not working.

For more specificity, I'm trying to default to gnome-classic instead of gnome. I want to turn on the computer, log in as any arbitrary user, and see gnome-classic, not gnome3 (preferably I'd remove the gnome3 default session, if there's a way to do that).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Debian, you should set the `x-session-manager` default command to choose your default session manager:

```
# update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

There, you can select the session manager you want GDM3 to use by default.

If `gnome-session-classic` does not appear in the listing, try creating the link on your own. Something like the following:

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-session-manager x-session-manager /usr/bin/gnome-session-classic 60
```

Then you should be able to select gnome-classic with `update-alternatives --config x-session-manager`.

To customize the session managers listed by GDM, I think the only way is to go to `/usr/share/xsessions` and create/remove *Desktop Entry* files there. The format is easy to understand, but in case you need help, you can consult [the Desktop Entry specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) or [the GNOME documentation about Desktop Entry files](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for being MIA, I didn't go into work for a few days.

Comment: What does `60` in `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-session-manager x-session-manager /usr/bin/gnome-session-classic 60` mean ?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut It's the priority. Just for the folks still wondering.

Answer (score 3):

With GDM, have you tried modifying your `~/.dmrc` file? You can set gnome classic as your default session like this:

```
[Desktop]
Session=gnome-classic
```

reference: [GDM manual](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#sessionconfig)

Comment: This is not preferable, since I'd like it to be global, and not per user.

Comment: my `.dmrc` says `Session=cinnamon` but it's ignored. Maybe it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

try to edit /etc/gdm/custom.conf:

```
[daemon]
DefaultSession=gnome-classic
```

but I think that by default it will offer you the last used for that user anyway...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select default x-session

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

if you want to remove x-session options
first list their path by

```
update-alternatives --list x-session-manager
```

then remove option by

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove x-session-manager /usr/bin/gnome-session
```